# Django intersection based on common field

Tags: django, django-models

I have chat and participant models.

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    ...
class Participant(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participants')
    participant = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I'm looking for a way to check if there exists a single chat with two specified users.

Edit: I've thought of using "in" on the nested objects but am unsure how to require both.

```
qs = Chat.objects.filter(participants__participant__in[user_a,user_b])
```

This query selects each chat the participant is in but I want only the chats where both participants are in

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query which can be used in the required view or model definition.

- Filter the chat items with user A
- Filter the chat user B with chat__pk in first query set

  ```py
  qs_first = Chat.objects.filter(
         participants__participant = user_a).values('pk')
  qs_second = Chat.objects.filter( pk__in = qs_first,
         participants__participant = user_b)
  ```

This is considering user_a and user_b are a objects of the **CustomUser** class.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain calls to `filter` which will `and` your filter conditions:

```
qs = Chat.objects.filter(
    participants__participant=user_a
).filter(
    participants__participant=user_b
)
```